# Azure Application Gateway w/ AKS Custom Domain Not Loading

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

My Registar is Google. I updated the nameservers to point to Azure in a DNS zone and have confirmed the Records are being sourced from Azure.

I am attempting to setup my custom domain to the application gateway Pubic IP address, so I have added the following configs below. When I hit the GW IP Directly the WebAPP loads but when hitting the custom domain that is pointing to the IP the web app does not load.

A Record Pointing to AppGW IP

[image: 1]

I have also attemtped to point [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) to the IP Address and that has not worked as well.

I am running an AKS cluster.

Listener Configuration

[image: 2]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The custom domain that is pointing to the IP the web app does not load. These issues may occur if you have not added your own app gateway public Ip address value in DNS record please check the below following workaround for reference: -

After creating a DNS, try to add IP address by adding a record set as shown below.
[image]

For getting Ip address ***Go to your application gateway -> overview -> double click on frontend public Ip address***

[image]

Try using this IP address on that record set.

[image]

In your public DNS record set, once Ip address value is added, custom domain will point to that IP. your DNS server will be visited first, where the IP address is visible, it returns back and come to your server. Once it arrives, an ‘A’ host record for the IP address section will redirect the request to your IP address, and then it redirects the backend pool part to HTTP port 80.

[image]

[image]

The application gateway will handle load balancing if you try to create ***two backend pools,*** it will redirect the section to port 80 and connect to your backend target using that port.

Additionally, please check this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73367486/how-to-use-private-dns-zone-which-will-be-used-when-we-access-our-website-from-o/73375118#73375118) *by kartik* as it contains some useful information.