# How to use private dns zone which will be used when we access our website from our client vm in azure.How to configure dns zone for client virtual

Tags: azure, iis, webserver, azure-dns

I configured the private DNS zone so that the client Virtual machine( which I created in it) can connect to the webserver( Which I created in Azure with loadbalancer ).I also did the network peering between vnet 1 and vnet2 which are private. vnet 1 is for webserver 1 and webserver2( I created this virtual machine and did virtual peering with webserver1).
After login to client I am trying to reach website mst300-lb.harmandeep14.com
mst300lb is my load balancer name
harmandeepkaur14.com is my privated dns zone name
I created the  feature iis in webserver 1 and webserver2
I want to reach  mst300-lb.harmandeep14.com in client but I cannot
where I am going wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yXqI.png)

What should I do view this website on client virtual machine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBZBF.png)
This is load ip address.
and that's the record I created in loadbalancer.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZviZ.png)

Comment: How did you configure your load balancer? This link may help you: [Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing).

Comment: Is the private dns zone linked to vnet1 and vnet2? Did you create a dns record for mst300-lb? Maybe as first step try to connect through ip - does that work?

Answer (score 0):

•   From what you have configured the environment, `I can understand that you have configured the two webservers in the same virtual network, i.e., VNET1 and the client VM from where you are accessing the IIS webpage hosted on the webservers is hosted in virtual network 2, i.e., VNET2 and you have configured peering between them so that the client VM can access the IIS webpage hosted on the webserver pool configured as a backend in the load balancer`.

Thus, you will have to **create a CNAME record in your private DNS zone for the load balancer name with the alias as the actual name of the IIS webpage/website hosted on the servers** as shown below in the snapshot: -

[image: Private DNS zone]

•   Once you **create a CNAME record for the IIS webpage in your private DNS zone with the alias as the FQDN of the load balancer, ensure that an ‘A’ host record also exists for the load balancer such that the CNAME record can track and resolve the load balancer from here itself. Also do ensure that you have configured virtual network links with both the virtual networks as shown below in the snapshot for webservers and client VMs to be added in here**.

Since, you are using private DNS zone, I would also recommend you **create ‘A’ host records for both the webservers as well as client VMs, this will ensure that for your private network, every resource is registered in the appropriate DNS zone and the request for accessing the webpage is routed correctly to the backend resources**. Also, ensure that the webpage/website **application hosted on the webservers also have an ‘A’ host record in the private DNS zone created which will in effect load balance the traffic received on the frontend to the backend webservers and the webpages/websites hosted on them**.

[image: Load balancer]
[image: Load balancer - 2]

Also, do **`ensure that the website if hosted internally on port 80 TCP HTTP, then ensure that the health probe is configured accordingly in the load balancer rules for the traffic over HTTP port 80 to be routed and load balanced further to the backend pools`**.

Comment: I added the CNAME record and A record but I still not working